# Facebook Graph API: manage my fanpage without app review?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, web

I'd like to develop a simple web app to automatically post status updates on behalf of a Page I'm admin of. 
If I understand the docs correctly, I need to:

1. login to facebook with app id & app secret and ask for `manage_pages` permission
2. retrieve Page Access Token from `/me/accounts`
3. use that Page Access Token to work with my Page

the thing is, I need to have my application reviewed by Facebook in order to be able to request `manage_pages` (extended) permission. However to undergo the review successfully my app needs to be functional.

How am I supposed to develop properly working app when I can't even test it against Graph API as I don't have the page access token?

Is there really no way to generate long-lasting Page Access Token manually and provide it to my web app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don´t need to go through the review process if it´s only an App for you. `manage_pages` works without review for every User with a role in the App (Admin, Developer, Tester).

Comment: unfortunately, it does not. I'm an admin of the app I've just created and when requesting the manage_pages I get the following message: http://i.imgur.com/rBct3oF.png
According to the docs, this is the case with apps created on or after 30 April 2014 (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login#post-f8-apps) . I have some older "unused" apps, and for them, I get the similar warning saying my apps might stop working after 30 April 2015 if they don't undergo review.

Comment: Ok, nevermind. I've created one more new app and this time the permissions is granted for me.

Comment: may have been a bug. that message is just a warning that you need go to through review if you want to make the app available in public.